# Regex to whitelist html tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm trying to create a regex that could whitelist a few set of html tags.

```
/<(\/)?(code|em|ul)(\/)?>$/
```

But there are few cases where this is failing:

```
<em style="padding: 10px">
```

So tried `/<(\/)?(code|em|ul)(.|\n)*?(\/)?>$/` but this also allows

`<emadchgasgh style="padding: 10px">`

Cases that need to be whitelisted:

```
<em> - Success
</em> - Success
<br/> - Success
<em style="asdcasc"> - Success
<emacjhasjdhc> - Failure
```

**Question-** What else could be added to the regex?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the regex? Is using regex required for the problem?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I get a string of HTMl on server. So need to validate if only whitelisted tags are added to it and not others

Comment: So this is in Node, is that right?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Java on server, but since it needs to be validated on client first, so javascript there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/<\s*\/?\s*(code|em|ul|br)\b.*?>/
```

`\s*\/?\s*` There may be spaces before the name of the tag
`(code|em|ul|br)\b` Matches only the whole tag name
`.*?>` Matching everything to the character `>`

Answer (score 3):

On client-side, parse the text into a document with DOMParser and use `querySelector` to select an element which is not `code`, `em` `ul`, or `br` with the query string:

```
*:not(code):not(em):not(ul):not(br)
```

If anything is returned, the string does not pass.

```js
const test = (str) => {
  const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
  return !doc.body.querySelector('*:not(code):not(em):not(ul):not(br)');
};

console.log(test('foo <br> bar'));
console.log(test('foo <code>code here</code> bar <br>'));
console.log(test('foo <div>not allowed</div>'));
```

In Java, you can use [`Jsoup`](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) to parse a given HTML string, and then you can select elements inside it, eg:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input);
Elements forbiddenElements = doc.select("*:not(code):not(em):not(ul):not(br)");
```

If `forbiddenElements` has anything in it, the string contains forbidden elements.

Comment: Can we do it with a regex ? Need to be done on server side also

Comment: You should generally never use a regular expression to parse HTML if at all possible when better alternatives are available. I'm sure Java has methods of DOM parsing that'll provide something equivalent to `querySelector`